# Syntax error in IFF Access query

Tags: ms-access, syntax

I keep getting the following error on my query: Syntax error (comma) in query expression 'Invoice_Header.[IIf([Document_Date]<5/1/2018,"1%","2%")'.

This is my query: Rate: IIf([Document_Date]<5/1/2018,"1%","2%")

If I take out the table field: Invoice_Header, the query goes through, but it marks everything as 2% even though I know that there are records going back to before May 1, 2018 that should be 1%.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you construct an example that can be shared? Is the error referring to invoice_Header or referring, or does `Rate: IIf([Document_Date]<5/1/2018,"1%","2%")` gives you an error as well?

Comment: The query is referencing a column called Document_Date in a table called Invoice_Header. This column contains dates. Does this info help?

Answer (score 0):

Got a tip on another forum. . . something I had tried, but for some reason it worked this time. I delimited the date.

Rate: IIf([Document_Date]< #5/1/2018#,"1%","2%")